# Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.?

Tags: reactjs, mern

it says here that error is in manifest.json
but I can't figure out what is to change or to fix

```
{
  "short_name": "slroofing",
  "name": "slroofing",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

it says here that error is in manifest.json
but I can't figure out what is to change or to fix

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Comment: and here also
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: i dont think there is any problem with your json file where are you getting the error your issue might be from where you are referencing it

Comment: and this one also Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'